# Neovim 'tab' or 'vert' no longer splits, just creates buffer

Tags: neovim, vim-windows, split

When I start a neovim session, my first command is to startup a terminal session within vim. However lately (perhaps due to an OSX update?) any use of `vert` or `tab` no longer performs a vertical split, but takes the full screen. This had been working prior to an OSX update, with no changes to my vimrc, or nevoid version.

Now `vert term` or just `vert` seems to create a new buffer with those contents.

```
:ls                                                                                                                                                                                                        
  1 #h   "simulate/simulate.py"         line 1
  2 %aR  "term://~/ws/hello-ltr/notebooks/elasticsearch/vmware//4680:/bin/zsh" line 1
```

Quitting vim `:q` causes both buffers to close.

I have tried fully exiting the terminal and restarting, nothing seems to address the issue.

As a temporary workaround I simply do `CtrlW+v` and get to the setup I want.

Comment: I have the same behavior on Windows 10 and Neovim 0.7. But as mentioned with Vim 8.2 a new vertical buffer spending 50% of the space is created.